# What is the best way to update one-to-many relationships from DTO inside aggregate?

Tags: symfony, collections, doctrine, one-to-many, dto

I have problem with updating Order Items from DTO. In application I have Order Edit page, which sends a request being converted to DTO:

```
class OrderData
{
    /**
     * @var string|null
     */
    protected $date;

    /**
     * @var array|OrderItemData[]
     */
    protected $orderItemsData;

    (...)
}
```

Order item data:

```
class OrderItemData
{
    /**
     * @var int|null
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var float|null
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     */
    protected $quantity;

    (...)
}
```

The Order entity has mapping:

```
class Order
{
    /**
     * @var Collection|OrderItem[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderItem", mappedBy="order", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $orderItems;

    (...)
}
```

What is the best solution to update `$order->orderItems` collection from array of `OrderItemData`? The worse thing is that Order Edit allows three types of modifications to OrderItem list:

- current order item can be changed
- current order item can be removed
- new order item can be created

As a workaround I used to clear all order items from order, and then iterate through array of OrderItemData and create new ones, but that solution was workaround and now it's time to do something better with it.

I found many pages in Internet, that are encouraging to use DTO classes even as Symfony Form data class, but I didn't found solution to problem of updating collections. Anybody can give me any advice?

Comment: The question you ask is somewhat opinionated, since there is - as far as I know - no built-in solution to handle the DTO stuff.

If you're not worried about `OrderItem`s being removed and added a lot, your solution is already passable, since it's simple above all.

Answer (score 1):

if you build REST API you must create actions like this (ant now worry about nested collections):

```
POST /order/orderItem to add
PUT /order/orderItem/{id} to update
DELETE /order/orderItem/{id} to delete
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems fine, because in this approach we exactly know what user want's to do, but... To use this approach we must modify the flow of application. Currently user (in our case administrator) is editing the order on the single view and when he's sure everything is ok - he's clicking submit button and complete order data is going to backend.

Comment: To do order editing in the above way, we will need to store draft order somewhere in backend, user will edit via REST endpoints the draft and when he will finish he will submit the form. This will also cause more requests to our backend, but our orders wont have much lines, which is acceptable. If I wouldn't find other way to do this probably I will refactor the code to use this solution.

Comment: In my current project, we use the AutomapperPlus library for mapping request->DTO and DTO->Entity. And in places when we need to modify nested collection, we just clear and recreate collection items using setter. (We have small nested collections 2-5 items)

    public function setPrices(array $prices): self
    {
        $this->prices->clear();
        foreach ($prices as $price) {
            $this->addPrice($price);
        }

        return $this;
    }
This is best approach for us =)

Comment: I stick with recreating collections, thank you for your help :)